Text above cards
I'm trying to align the text "Zarząd" above my cards but, everything I have tried doesn't work. I've tried every way that I could think of, I'm a beginner so I'm still learning. I tried adding new styles, columns, displays, etc.
This is the most recent attempt at the fix:


#zarzad {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container section {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#zarzad h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.card .info {
  padding: 15px;
}

.card h3,
.card p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #eee;
}
<section id="zarzad">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Zarząd</h2>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/637347195623833630/71891a4d1cd9795017d08953adb04cdb.png" alt="Zarząd 1">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Bakłażan</h3>
        <p>Właściciel</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/314066973879304203/4207e8071ce2f216fac7d188e17a8502.png" alt="Zarząd 1">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Templariusz</h3>
        <p>Zarząd</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



This is how it should look

I realise that English is - probably - not your first language, but what do you mean by "above [your] cards"? Running the code in your question, the heading of "Zarząd" is placed vertically "above" your cards in the layout, so without more detail about your expectations your code appears to be working.

You would need to put the cards in another container separate from the <h2> text.
Then make it a flexbox.
See this this example:


#zarzad {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container section {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#zarzad h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.card .info {
  padding: 15px;
}

.card h3,
.card p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #eee;
}
<section id="zarzad">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Zarząd</h2>

    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/637347195623833630/71891a4d1cd9795017d08953adb04cdb.png" alt="Zarząd 1">
        <div class="info">
          <h3>Bakłażan</h3>
          <p>Właściciel</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/314066973879304203/4207e8071ce2f216fac7d188e17a8502.png" alt="Zarząd 1">
        <div class="info">
          <h3>Templariusz</h3>
          <p>Zarząd</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>





#zarzad {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container section {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.child {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
.card {
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#zarzad h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.card .info {
  padding: 15px;
}

.card h3,
.card p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #eee;
}

<section id="zarzad">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Zarząd</h2>
    <div class = "child">


Bakłażan
Właściciel

Templariusz
Zarząd


#zarzad {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container section {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#zarzad h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.card .info {
  padding: 15px;
}

.card h3,
.card p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #eee;
}
<section id="zarzad">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Zarząd</h2>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/637347195623833630/71891a4d1cd9795017d08953adb04cdb.png" alt="Zarząd 1">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Bakłażan</h3>
        <p>Właściciel</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/314066973879304203/4207e8071ce2f216fac7d188e17a8502.png" alt="Zarząd 1">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Templariusz</h3>
        <p>Zarząd</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



